# How to make Angular Material Chips static?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to do something similar to this: https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.9/demo/chips#static-chips where the chips aren't selectable, clickable or hoverable and just want it to be a static chip. However, I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) for this.

Is it possible to do the same thing with Angular Material? I know there's a [Static Content](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.9/demo/chips#static-chips) section in the Angular Material documentations where you do:

```
<mat-chip-set role="list">
  <mat-chip role="listitem"> Sugar </mat-chip>
  <mat-chip role="listitem"> Spice </mat-chip>
  <mat-chip role="listitem"> Everything Nice </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-set>
```

However, I tried that and it didn't work. Basically what I want to do:

1. Remove the grey color when you hover over the mat-chip
2. Remove the ripple effect when you click on the mat-chip (I found you can do this doing `[disableRipple]="true"`?)
3. Remove the grey color when you click on the mat-chip

I don't want any effect at all when you hover or click on the chip. Is there a way to do this with angular material? Here is how my code looks at the moment:

```
<mat-chip-list class="privacy-tags">
  <mat-chip>Public</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Private</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Confidential</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**EDIT:** This is what happens when I do:

```
.mat-chip {
    color: magenta !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 1px magenta solid !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}

.mat-chip:hover {
    background-color: unset !important;
}
```

The tag on the left is clickable and the tab on the right isn't clickable:

[image]

If there's only one tag:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the ripple effect by defining to `disableRipple` as `true`. For the hover effect, you could customize the `mat-chip` element like the following, FYI, I tested this with Angular Material v15 which has `mat-chip-listbox` instead of `mat-chip-list`:

**component template HTML**

```html
<mat-chip-listbox>
  <mat-chip [disableRipple]="true">Public</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip [disableRipple]="true">Private</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip [disableRipple]="true">Confidential</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

**component .scss styles**

```css
mat-chip {
  pointer-events: none; // maybe use it along with !important

  &:hover {
    background-color: unset; // maybe use it along with !important
  }
}
```

**Or .css**:

```css
mat-chip {
  pointer-events: none;
}

mat-chip:hover {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this got rid of the hover but I'm still able to click on the chip... Was the `pointer-events: none;` suppose to get rid of it being clickable?

Comment: For future uses, you can disable the selectabel effect as following

`<mat-chip disableRipple selectable="false">Private</mat-chip>`

Answer (score 0):

use **mat-basic-chip-option**  or **mat-basic-chip** instead of **mat-chip** , this will allow you to customize your css :

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-basic-chip {
          border: 1px solid #cccccc;
          border-radius: 16px;
          width: 124px;
          height: 32px;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
          &.mat-mdc-chip-selected {
            border: 2px solid purple;
            ;
            width: 114px;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: default;
          }
          &:hover {
            background-color: white !important;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Two options

1. use `<mat-chip>`
2. use disabled with css

```
<mat-chip-set aria-label="Fish selection">
  <mat-chip>Two fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip-option disabled class='chip'>Warn fish</mat-chip-option>
</mat-chip-set>
```

[Here is the code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1vh96?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchips-overview-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstyle.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)